# Calculating walking time and driving time from dataset coordinates (British National Grid:Eastling&Northling)?

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, driving-distance, travel-time

I am trying to find a way to get the travel time for both walking and driving for my dataset. Using ArcGIS I was able to get the liner/planar line that connects them but I do not know how to get the travel times. After days spent trying, I am switching to a more practical solution in R!

edit: I have a dataset with 2 sets of coordinates, origin and destination, where each point has its own origin (where the journey started) and a destination (where the journey ended). What I want to do is calculate the driving time and the walking time for these points.

Thank you!

Comment: So, I have a basemap layer with just my points (origin) and my destinations. they are already linked by ID so each origin point has its own destination. What I am trying to do is get the car driving time form origin to destination and the walking time too. I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

Google is perhaps the best API for driving distance, Googleway is an R package allowing you to compute distances

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleway/versions/2.7.1

I did the same kind of task but directly from Gsheet/Appscript then sending it back to R:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions

I'm not sure it answers your question but hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out; I am just wondering, how did you convert your coordinates? I am assuming I need to use Long and Lat for that right?

Comment: Has I said i did it on appscript. I had a vector of adresses and google maps api handle adresses. But there is also a function to go from adress to lat / long: var geo = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(adress).results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lng  I believe you can reverse it if needed. I would usually not advise someone to use google and gsheet instead of R, but really... they currently have the best API for road distance.

Comment: Thank you :) I will check it out!